# Flutter Audio Recorder Plugin records M4A as WAV file

Tags: flutter, audio, codec, aac, m4a

When trying to extract a section of audio using FFMPEG I discovered that the .M4A file I thought was recorded by Flutter Audio Recorder was actually being recorded as a WAV file. Here's what FFMPEG reports;

```
  Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : mono
  Input #0, wav, from 'myaudio.m4a':
  Duration: 00:00:04.02, bitrate: 705 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
```

I'm guessing it's because I've boosted the sample rate in Flutter Audio recorder up from the default 16K to 44K in order to achieve higher quality.

```
  _recorder = FlutterAudioRecorder(customPath, audioFormat: AudioFormat.AAC, sampleRate: 44100);
```

So does the 44K boost mean I lose the benefit of the AAC compression and its smaller file size?

Here's a sample of the M4A file recorded by Flutter Audio Recorder;

https://speaktestbucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/63-talk-87.m4a

Here's the actual Flutter Audio Recorder plugin I'm using;

https://github.com/meghead/flutter_audio_recorder2

Which is a fork of;

https://github.com/hanyska/flutter_audio_recorder2

Which is itself a fork of the original Flutter Audio Recorder;

https://github.com/rmbrone/flutter_audio_recorder

Comment: M4A or WAV are containers, not codecs. Codec is AAC as per your flutter call. And AAC can support upto 96 kHz. Can you post a sample M4A from your recorder?

Comment: Sure! I edited the OP with the link.

Comment: once audio becomes digital (whether its synthesized or sampled from analog ) there is no way to "achieve higher quality" by altering sample rate or bit depth which are the two fundamental aspects of digital audio

Comment: My apologies. What I meant was I boosted the default 16K in the Flutter Audio Recorder settings to 44K in order to achieve higher quality (than the default 16K). I'm wondering if that in itself may be the reason why FFMPEG thinks its a wav rather than an M4A file. or is it possible that Flutter Audio Recorder is wrapping it as a wav file because it is at 44K?

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that the size of the input seems quite larger than the output even considering that it has been trimmed. Here's the FFMPEG command; ffmpeg -vn -ss 00:00:01 -i input.m4a -t 00:00:03 -c:a aac output.m4a

Comment: @Gyan is the expectation that a container with file extension `.m4a` will always have AAC encoded audio? `.mp4` container supports LPCM audio so it may be worth clarifying.

Comment: ffmpeg does not support muxing PCM into MP4, so AAC remains the best choice.

Comment: @Gyan OPs question suggests they have PCM data contained in the m4a. Also, I can forgive the confusion of mixing up containers and codecs when the terminology is freely exchanged in certain circumstances e.g WAV for PCM , which appears to demonstrates by the report from FFMPEG in the question. I suppose the question boils down to _does this m4a file contain pcm data or aac data ?_

Comment: They definitely have PCM data but it's not a real m4a; it's a WAV. See the 2nd line of the log snippet.

Comment: @Meggy @Gyan is correct, data in your linked  file starts `52494646 246A0500 57415645 666D7420` (`RIFF$jWAVEfmt`) It is just a `.wav` file with a `m4a` extension. That does indeed suggest **Flutter Audio Recorder Plugin** is recording wav format regardless of the file extension you stipulate

Comment: Gyan or fdcpp if you put your last repsonses as an answer, I will select it.

Comment: @Gyan I think this is all yours

Comment: The actual Q is whether 44K sampling rate will cause Flutter to force WAV / PCM output. Only a flutter dev / user can answer that.

Comment: @Gyan In this case the Flutter plug-in under discussion is suspect at best. Flutter does not deal with with audio on it’s own. I think it would be more accurate to say that their is grounds for a bug / issue to be flagged against the project in question. However, no plug-in has been explicitly referenced, no documentation has been linked to so it is difficult to say for definite that the behaviour of the plug-in is incorrect. From the sounds of things, it looks like the plug-in is at least behaving unexpectedly

Comment: @Meggy it would be a good idea to link to the specific flutter plug-in you mention in the question. A link to the `FlutterAudioRecorder` docs would avoid others doing the heavy lifting

Comment: Here's the actual Flutter Audio Recorder plugin I'm using;

https://github.com/meghead/flutter_audio_recorder2

Which is a fork of;

https://github.com/hanyska/flutter_audio_recorder2

Which is itself a fork of the original Flutter Audio Recorder;

https://github.com/rmbrone/flutter_audio_recorder

Comment: This appears to be a known issue https://github.com/rmbrone/flutter_audio_recorder/issues/9

Comment: Thanks for that info fdcpp. I thought I had searched carefully through the issues but clearly not carefully enough. This solves the mystery. If you put it as an answer I can select it.

Comment: Technically the question should have been flagged as off topic and closed as it comes down to a bug that was already known. That is more a failing of the SO community than yourself. What might give the question is drawing up an answer yourself, digesting what has been relevant in these comments and quotes/references where necessary, including what signs indicated a bug (m4a that is actually a wav &c.). Let’s chalk it up as experience.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a fork of rmbones' Flutter_Audio_Recorder which records a properly encoded M4A file.

https://github.com/hnvn/flutter_audio_recorder

Some of the dependencies were out of date so I ended up forking hnvn's fork with an updated pubspec.yaml;

https://github.com/meghead/flutter_audio_recorder

The resulting short file is an impressive 8.2k in size.

https://speaktestbucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/290-628.m4a